# App is crashing due to OOM while running 20K rules in drool engine

Tags: cloud, drools

We have one spring boot app which runs on internal cloud with predefined memory of 8 GB.
Our app has close to 20K drools rule setup, app started crashing quite often with OOM.
when we did profiling, it was found that rules are taking 50% memory while starting itself, then memory is keep increasing and finally crashes.

We are using StateFulSession as of now and making sure dispose() method is called.. does using Stateless session works in this case?

Since its deployed in internal cloud, getting heapdump is hard.. what are other possibility to get it fixed or diagnose it?

We also have MetaSpace defined of 512MB.

Comment: Pretty sure you're doing something wrong, either in rule design, how you're configured, or how you're executing. I ran 1 million rules on 8 gb memory and was cpu bound not memory bound, with uptime of ~6 months. Rule heap dumps aren't particularly easy to read -- what version of Drools are you using?

Comment: Also it makes sense that you see a spike in memory usage on startup -- the rules have to get read into memory. Once they're in memory, they have to stay there in order to be executed. That behavior is normal and expected. Check that the objects you're passing _into_ working memory serialize cleanly and with a small footprint.

Comment: We are using version 7.5 version..  yes starting behavior I agree its expected.. since heap dump is not available we are not sure what causing memory usage going high..  can you please comment if you are using Statefull Session or stateless one?

Comment: I've only ever used stateful sessions. Have you tried deploying your application into a non-cloud environment that you can more easily control and monitor? Are you using session pooling?

Comment: yeah we are are using session pool..

Comment: In addition to the facts inserted explicitly, do you do any kind of enrichment by the rules themselves? How many rules do you have and how many facts at maximum needed for single rule to execute? Do you have rules that operate large amount of data? Do you have parallel processing of your rules, if so how is it organized?